# How to edit another applications memory in C (Bypassing Protected mode)?

Tags: c, windows, memory-editing

I want to know how to bypass protected mode in Windows 8.1, so that my C programs can access the memory of other applications and change their values...I know it can be done because I used to use memory editors to hack games; I just want to build one myself. Below is just a basic program that I threw together just to see if I could write a program that could simulate such an action. It works; of course the problem is that because of protected mode it will crash if I try to access memory outside the scope of the program.

```
    /* Allows the user to view regions of computer memory */

    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    typedef unsigned char BYTE;

    unsigned int addr;
    int integer;
    float flt;

    void print_addr();
    void edit_addr(void);

    int main(void)
    {
        integer = 100;
        flt = 5.6;
        char ch;

        printf("Address of main function:    %x\n", (unsigned int) main);
        printf("Address of addr variable:    %x\n", (unsigned int) &addr);

        do {
            printf("Address of integer variable: %x\n", (unsigned int) &integer);
            printf("Address of flt variable:     %x\n", (unsigned int) &flt);
            printf("Value of (int)integer variable: %d\n", integer);
            printf("Value of (float)flt variable:   %.2f\n\n", flt);
            printf(" ----------------------------------------\n");
            printf("|       1 - Edit Address                 |\n");
            printf("|       2 - Print Memory                 |\n");
            printf(" ----------------------------------------\n");
            printf("\tEnter choice: ");
            scanf(" %c", &ch);
            switch(ch) {
                case '1': edit_addr(); break;
                case '2': print_addr(); break;
                default: printf("You entered an invalid menu item\n");
            };

            printf("\nWould you like to continue? ");
            scanf(" %c", &ch);
            putchar('\n');
        } while (toupper(ch) != 'N');

        return 0;
    }

    void print_addr(void)
    {
        int i, n;
        BYTE *ptr;

        printf("\nEnter a (hex) address: ");
        scanf("%x", &addr);
        printf("Enter number of bytes to view: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        printf("\n");
        printf(" Address              Bytes              Characters\n");
        printf(" -------  -----------------------------  ----------\n");

        ptr = (BYTE *) addr;
        for (; n > 0; n -= 10) {
            printf("%8X  ", (unsigned int) ptr);
            for (i = 0; i < 10 && i < n; i++)
                printf("%.2X ", *(ptr + i));
            for (; i < 10; i++)
                printf("   ");
            printf(" ");
            for (i = 0; i < 10 && i < n; i++) {
                BYTE ch = *(ptr + i);
                if (!isprint(ch))
                    ch = '.';
                printf("%c", ch);
            }
            printf("\n");
            ptr += 10;
        }
    }

    void edit_addr(void)
    {
        int n, int_value, *int_ptr;
        float flt_value, *flt_ptr;

        printf("\n ----------------------------------------\n");
        printf("|       1 - Integer                      |\n");
        printf("|       2 - Float                        |\n");
        printf(" ----------------------------------------\n");
        do {
            printf("\tEnter choice: ");
            scanf(" %d", &n);
        } while (n != 1 && n != 2);

        printf("\nEnter a (hex) address: ");
        scanf("%x", &addr);

        printf("Enter the value: ");
        switch(n) {
            case 1:
                int_ptr = (int *) addr;
                scanf("%d", &int_value);
                *int_ptr = int_value;
                break;
            case 2:
                flt_ptr = (float *) addr;
                scanf("%f", &flt_value);
                *flt_ptr = flt_value;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Standard C has no concept that would allow this.  Therefore, any solution is platform-specific.  Please identify which o/s you want to do this on.  The answers will be radically different between Windows and Unix-like systems, and there will probably be differences in detail between different Unix-like systems.  I'd not be very surprised to learn there are differences in what can be done between different versions of Windows, either.  And it will require elevated privileges to work at all; memory is supposed to be private to a process.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler I am running off of Windows 8.1

Comment: You'll either need to be running as part of the kernel, or the permissions to use whatever systems calls to do this may exist.

Comment: Alright, I'll look into that...I haven't learned about messing around with the kernel.

Comment: Also, look into ASLR. It randomizes the location of various segments of memory used by a process when it starts, so even if someone has the ability to break the protected mode model, it would more likely crash the process than hijack it.

Comment: Thanks I will look into that as well, I want to learn the in's and out's of C, eventually I am going to learn to program in assembly, I know the basics and can interpret most assembly code because I used to use softice back in the day...but a lot has changed especially with 64 bit processors

Comment: Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5570/Stealing-Program-s-Memory